# Upload configurable product using magmi

Tags: magento-1.7, magmi

I am trying to upload configurable product using magmi

Here is my csv

```
sku  |  attribute_set  |  type  |  category_ids  |  name  |  shoes_size  |  configurable_attributes
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
config-test_new  |  Default configurable  |  116  |  Config Test Product New  |  L, XL  |  shoes_size
```

I even tried to use simple_skus column like this

```
sku  |  attribute_set  |  type  |  category_ids  |  name  |  shoes_size configurable_attributes  |  simples_skus
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
config-test_new  |  Default configurable  |  116  |  Config Test Product New  |  L, XL shoes_size  |  KR0050967,KR0050968
```

But didn't work.

Can anyone tell me how can i create configurable products using magmi

Comment: did you check the configurable plugin in your magmi profile ?

Answer (score 0):

1. In your Magmi configuration, make sure you have the **Configurable Item processor** plugin enabled.
2. Set **Perform simples/configurable link** in the **Configurable Item processor** plugin to yes.
3. Make sure that the skus listed in the **simple_skus** column (`KR0050967,KR0050968`) are in your CSV (above your configurable item records), or that they already exist in Magento.